# Slide up activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity and another activity.
I want my first activity to end when I slide up the screen. The animation should be like the activity is sliding up too. Like the notification screen.
Is that possible? I have done many Google searches before posting this question, but could not get anything.

P.S - I don't want this to be seen as a casual question since there is no code shown. I just need some point to start and I am completely baffled.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

make an anim folder in res->

Make an xml file in anim folder slide_up_info.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

slide_down_info.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

no_change.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Now when you want to activity up then write below code

```
Intent intent_info = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ToActivity.class);
startActivity(intent_info);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_info,R.anim.no_change);
```

For down Activity animation

```
Intent intent_home=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent_home);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_change,R.anim.slide_down_info);
```

Comment: I couldn't understand just one thing. The last block of code, what does it do?

Comment: for down activity animation you can write last block code. intested of intent you can you finish() and overidepending also

Comment: this works just as i need it to, however it could be smoother; is there any way to get a REALLY smooth sliding effect?

Comment: @PankajAndroid: it should be 
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_down_info,R.anim.no_change);

Comment: for smoothness, use an interpolater. e.g. <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" >

Answer (score 0):

Animations can be introduced to Activity Launch using `OverridePendingTransition`. Take a look at this example where they have showed a sample code. [Animation between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927272/animation-between-activity-with-android)

To end an activity, you can call `finish()` on the first activity.

The know about the slideup, you can check `onFling` from [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) or `onTouch` from [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Comment: why would he call finish() ? he is launching a new Activity with startActivity, isn't he ?

Comment: From @rockydgeekgod question "I want my first activity to end when I slide up the screen" I assume he wants to close the first activity and remove it from the back stack. If he doesn't want to finish it and would like to navigate back, then there is no need to finish().

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way :  in your animation, override the onAnimationEnd method, and use startActivity in it to launch your new activity after the end of the animation